# Is there a way in Excel for a single formula to copy multiple cells to multiple cells?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

Basically what I'm wanting to do is with one formula, I want to copy the values and formatting from a range of cells to another range of cells.

| - | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Text & Formatting | Text & Formatting | Text & Formatting |
| 2 | Text & Formatting | Text & Formatting | Text & Formatting |
| 3 | Text & Formatting | Text & Formatting | Text & Formatting |

| - | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Formula Goes Here & Copies A1 | Copies A2 | Copies A3 |
| 2 | Copies B1 | Copies B2 | Copies B3 |
| 3 | Copies C1 | Copies C2 | Copies C3 |

Is this possible?

Comment: Formulas will not copy formatting.  You will need VBA in a subroutine to do that.

Comment: Formulas no... but what you want can be achieved using `Copy A1:C1 --> E1 - Paste Special (Values + Formatting) + Transpose`

Comment: Worksheet formulas result in VALUES not FORMATTING. You can assign multiple values from a range to another range with an Array Formula

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what Siddharth said above.

In VBA `Pastespecial` will do what you want. It can copy over everything from the cells and has a built-in transpose property.

Just paste this into a sub on your worksheet (not a module):

```
Range("A1:C3").Copy 'Change range to suit
Range("E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True 'E1 is the top left cell of where you want it pasted to.
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```